# Vim - Highlight too many closed brackets in Perl code

Tags: perl, vim

I'm trying to configure Vim so that it highlights extra closed brackets in Perl, for example ()**)**. For unclosed brackets this works correctly the extra ( is highlighted red. But the extra closed brackets are not highlighted.
This issue is only present when `syntax=perl`. When I use `syntax=c` or `syntax=vim` the unmatched closed brackets are correctly highlighted.

Here is an example with `syntax=perl`. The first row is fine but in the second row the extra ) is not red. :(

[image: perl syntax highlight]

Do you know any tricks or plugins that could solve this?
I've found some (very) old vim plugins like Highlight-UnMatched-Brackets but they didn't solve this issue for me.

Comment: Have you looked at syntastic to help with syntax issues? https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/Perl:---perl

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that this is a bug in the syntax highlight for Perl.  The project that keeps track of all the Perl-specific files that get fed back to the vim project is here: https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl (I'm one of the maintainers)  If you think it's a bug in the syntax highlighting, then go ahead and submit an issue on GitHub.

You might also try using the syntax files in the vim-perl project in your local vim.  I don't know what version of vim you're running, but it's possible newer support files will solve your problem.